# Upload Large Image & Crop Easier

Tags: php, crop, jcrop

I want to allow users to upload large photos of their home and crop it to fit properly into a slideshow. So I set it up that when the user uploads their large home photo it will store that and copy it and re-size the new copy to be a more manageable size. (ex. resizing a 5000x3333px image to 600x400px) Then this new image is displayed to the user to allow them to crop that image. After the image has been cropped 4 values are returned: x, y, w, and h. These are the values of the cropped area on the smaller image, but now we want to crop the original image not this smaller one. This means the w & h have to be increased and the x & y got to stay in correct position but this is the part that I'm so confused about. How do I properly scale up the w & h and keep x & y in right place to match the crop from the small image to the original large one?

Here is a code snippet of the final function that crops. This is using some of my homemade function, understand they are just there for convenience.

```
//User inputs from the crop area on the small image
$user_input_x = $_POST['x'];
$user_input_y = $_POST['y'];
$user_input_w = $_POST['w'];
$user_input_h = $_POST['h'];

//Grab original, small, and final image locations 
$original_image_src = '/tmp/original_image';
$small_image_src = '/tmp/small_image';
$final_image_location = '/final/image';

//Return the extension for both the original and small image
if(($image_ext = imageCheck($original_image_src)) === false) die('Could not find original image source!');
$original_image_src .= $image_ext;
$small_image_src .= $image_ext;
$final_image_location .= $image_ext;

//Get the width and height of both the original and small image
list($original_image_width, $original_image_height) = getimagesize($original_image_src);
list($small_image_width, $small_image_height) = getimagesize($small_image_src);

//Converts string location of image into php resource
//This function helps determine the type of image and create the resource
$src_image = createImage($original_image_src);

//This is the area where I am having trouble
//I need to scale up the users input x,y,w,h because they are from small image and need to match to original


//These are the vars to go into all the final fields
$src_x = $user_input_x;
$src_y = $user_input_y;
$src_w = 0;
$src_h = 0;

$crop_x = 0;
$crop_y = 0;
$crop_w = 0;
$crop_h = 0;

$final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_w, $crop_h);
if(!imagecopyresampled($final_image, $src_image, $crop_x, $crop_y, $src_x, $src_y, $crop_w, $crop_h, $src_w, $src_h)) die('Could not resmaple image!');

//Saves image to final location retains the extension and destroys the resource
if(imageSave($final_image, $final_image_location, $image_ext) === false) die('Count not save image!');
```

Oh and if it help any, this crop is being done by jCrop which is pretty much providing the x, y, w & h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand x and w, and y and h scale at the same ratio.

```
$crop_y = $original_image_height/$small_image_height*$user_input_y;
$crop_h = $original_image_height/$small_image_height*$user_input_h;
$crop_w = $original_image_width/$small_image_width*$user_input_w;
$crop_x = $original_image_width/$small_image_width*$user_input_x;
```

I drew this to try and visualise it.
http://i58.tinypic.com/32zm0it.jpg

Comment: I feel so stupid, I had a brain fart. This was the simple math I needed, thank you.